# Xidel utility alternative for ARM / Raspberry Pi?

Tags: html, xpath, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, xidel

Does any of you know of a utility similar to Xidel that works on ARM processors, specifically on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B?

I created a few Bash scripts on my x86_64 laptop that I am going to put on an always-on RPI when it will arrive, but I just found out that there isn't an ARM version of Xidel, which I used to extract data from HTML pages using XPATH.

Comment: Since Xidel is open source and was written in Delphi with Lazarus you may just recompile for ARM. I'm not sure aboutLazarus, but at least [Embarcadero can target ARM processors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946387/how-to-affect-delphi-xex-code-generation-for-android-arm-targets). I'd say, download the source and try to compile it for ARM.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try this first thing when my Pi will arrive. At least I'll also learn something new while doing that :D

Comment: any followup to this @Hori?

Comment: I gave up on xidel and wrote a small python script instead